# The invocation of signal handler and atexit handler in Python

Tags: python, signals, atexit

I have a piece of Python code as below:

```
import sys
import signal
import atexit

def release():
    print "Release resources..."

def sigHandler(signo, frame):
    release()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigHandler)
    atexit.register(release)

    while True:
        pass
```

The real code is far more complex than this snippets, but the structures are the same: i.e. main function maintains an infinite loop.

I need a signal callback to release the resources occupied, like DB handle.
Then I add a `SIGTERM` handler, in case the server is killed, which simply invoke the release function and then exit the process.
The `atexit` one aims to handling process complete successfully.

Now I have a problem I just want `release` to be invoked only once when the process is killed. Any improvement on my code?

Comment: I'd like to ask if it's really necessary to exit this way w/o graceful shutdown of the loop in `main`?

Comment: A widely used idiom would be to check if we should break the loop and then clearly release resources.

Comment: @user3159253 Hi, thank you for your fast response. I think yes, the main loop is a http server module in fact, and I have no access to interrupt the loop myself. Only Ctrl-C can stop it. Yes, it's name is bottle T_T.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) atexit handlers aren't executed if the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, or in case of internal error, or if `os._exit()` is called. So I would use something like this (almost copied your code):

```
import sys
import signal
import atexit

def release():
    print "Release resources..."

def sigHandler(signo, frame):
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    atexit.register(release)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigHandler)

    while True:
        pass
```

I've checked `release()` is called once and only once in case of both `TERM` (issued externally) and `INTR` signals (`Ctrl-C` from keyboard). If you need, you may install more signal handlers (e.g. for `HUP` etc). If you need "a more graceful shutdown", you should find a way to gracefully break the loop and/or install external "shutdown handlers" (in case of `SIGKILL` you won't get a chance to cleanly release resources) or simply make your application be [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).