# How to guarantee proper closing

Tags: python

I have an class I want to ensure closes properly. In particular, I want it to close even if my main process is killed from an external event (eg: SIGTERM).

Context managers and atexit will not be called if killed 'abnormally'. So I've been trying to use signal to capture events and  then run my particular cleanup code.

But now I'm getting into the weeds of how python cleans up upon different types of exits. For instance, while I can capture signal.SIGTERM and add my own handler, I don't know how to call the default handler when done. But not being an expert, I'm uncomfortable having my library take over proper system exit with my own code.

(Specifics: I'm using shelve and if you don't close a shelf it will remain in a locked and un-openable state - essentially unusable.)

Am I making this too hard? I would think making sure I can clean up properly should not require deep expertise.

Alternatively, if I really do need to capture the signal and then take over system exit, can I simply do my cleanup code, and if the only other handler is SIG_DFL, then I just do a sys.exit()? That sounds risky, but is that ok?

My current code:

```
def reg_sig(signum):
    old_handler = signal.getsignal(signum)

    def sighandler(signum, frame):
        close_open_objects() # <== my custom code
        if callable(old_handler):
            old_handler()
        else:
            # What goes here?
            # do_default_handler() # <- this seems ideal
            # or
            # sys.exit()

    try:
        # I'm not sure what signals might be called so I register a bunch.
        signal.signal(signum, sighandler) 
    except Exception as err:
        pass

# Register signals
for sig in [signal.SIGHUP, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGQUIT, signal.SIGABRT, 
            signal.SIGKILL,signal.SIGTERM]:
    reg_sig(sig)
```

Comment: Note that SIGKILL (and SIGSTOP) cannot be caught by the process receiving the signal. There are many more "external events" you cannot catch -- pulling the power source from the computer, for instance. What hostile environment are you coding for that requires you to try to catch all signals?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468042/the-invocation-of-signal-handler-and-atexit-handler-in-python#23468485

Comment: @MathiasRav - OP says this is a problem with a `shelve` database.

Comment: In C, you don't call the chained signal handler, you just reraise the exception. I assume python is the same. here is an example https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-in-Handler.html#Termination-in-Handler

Comment: The possible duplicate explains how to reraise, but not how to protect shelve.

Comment: @tdelaney Sorry, my question was aimed at which environment causes OP to expect hostile signals -- not why he needs to do any cleanup. I edited the question in my comment. I believe the duplicate does solve the issue (calling `close_open_objects` when receiving a signal), so I submitted an answer.

Comment: Seconded. If one has a hostile environment when it's not uncommon for a process to die without any prior warnings (SIGKILL, power outage), I think it's best to consider **not** trying to catch them, but implement more storage robustness and failure recovery. For example, using append-only log files, writing a new file instead of updating the old one, etc.. And, maybe, a `shelve` isn't a good choice, but something designed to be more resistant to random outages (e.g. PostgreSQL) is the way to go.

Comment: @MathiasRav - My environment isn't hostile and I can catch the expected SIGTERM. But if shelve EVER crashes without closing, it is permanently locked and permanently corrupted. That seems fairly unworkable to me, but I figured the safe thing is to make sure in any reasonable crash, I shut down shelf predictably.

Comment: @drdaeman I do, btw, have a workaround for shelf - I can force shelf to use _gdbm, which has a 'u' flag which doesn't lock the file. But that said, I agree with you - I think maybe a different DB might be the solution. Though shelf is standard lib and my needs are small, so I figured it should be an easy, solid, and reliable choice. Maybe that was a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use atexit and register a signal handler that calls `sys.exit(0)`. Beware that this changes the process exit code from what would normally be returned in case of a signal. From [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468042/the-invocation-of-signal-handler-and-atexit-handler-in-python#23468485):

```
import sys, atexit, signal
atexit.register(close_open_objects)  # Your custom code
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda n, f: sys.exit(0))
```

Comment: Question - is this exit essentially the equivalent of a normal SIGTERM (or other) close? My concern is that by me taking over SIGTERM, or a different signal, I will be changing python's exit behavior in a way that I don't understand. What if a SIGTERM should always print a stack trace, or register an event, or write home to mommy? I'm a little concerned about taking ownership of the kill event.

Comment: If you want your library component to be able to handle signals in a way that doesn't interfere with other components in the same process, then you need to add a facility to coordinate the different signal handlers. There's no such thing in the Python standard library, so you need to install a single signal handler in your application, and possibly allow components to hook into the signal handler somehow. Some component **must** take ownership of the kill event -- preferably a component dedicated to signal handling.

Comment: Ok - this is exactly what I was getting at. Just to confirm - there's no way to capture a signal, do my thing, and then re-raise it back to python's default signal handler, right?

Comment: There is no "Python's default signal handler" (except for SIGINT which raises KeyboardInterrupt). What you *can* do is set signal handling back to SIG_DFL and reraise the signal using os.kill, but that doesn't make any other Python code run -- it just sets the correct process exit code, and it seems to me that exiting with the right exit code is not important for your use case.

Comment: Got it. I had assumed that Python was doing something important I didn't want to mess with. And also setting it back to SIG_DFL and re-raising with os.kill makes a ton of sense. Thanks!